# Would there be any performance difference for CUDA blocksize 1024x1 vs 32x32?

Tags: performance, cuda, memory-bandwidth

How are these two block sizes (1024x1 vs 32x32) expected to perform from thread scheduling and memory bandwidth perspective? Is there any expected difference in performance of these 2 block sizes? Note that both use 1024 threads per block.

Comment: The number of ALU operations associated with the indexing can impact performance but it is often a minor percentage of the total instructions executed. Write the code both ways and diff the assembly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Threadblock dimensions, especially when we are talking about the same number of threads per block, don't by themselves affect performance.

Threads are still [grouped for execution into warps](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#thread-hierarchy).  The only direct effect of threadblock dimensions is to change the built-in variables e.g. `threadIdx.x`, `blockIdx.x`, etc. that are passed to each thread, which is not a performance issue.